# creating a registry file to run my application on windows startup

Tags: windows, registry

I have created a registry file that adds my application to start when windows starts,

here is the code,

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Userinit]


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows] 
"Ghori"="e:\Test\test.txt"
```

but when i add it to the registry, it successfully imports but when i goto regedit and look for it , it doesn't appear there :S

Comment: There's nothing in that registry file that would start your app when Windows starts (if you've posted the entire file). You've also said "it doesn't appear there" - where is "there"? It would also be useful to know what Windows version and whether or not you're running under an Administrator account.

Comment: it is Windows 7 64-bit , and yes i am using Administrator account and its a complete registry file, also when i said "there" that means i looked for it inside regedit and also searched for it for the string "ghori" but didn't find it, btw test.txt will be the name for my application in .exe format instead

Comment: If that's the complete file, then as I said before, there is nothing in that file that would start your app when Windows starts, which would explain why it doesn't work. :) That file does nothing but create a single string entry (incorrectly) under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce]
 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices]
 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce]
 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Userinit]


 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce]
 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices]
 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce]
 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows]

 "Ghori"="e:\\Test\\test.txt"
```

your
"Ghori"="e:\Test\test.txt" is missing '\\'

this is on my system and it works fine

```
     Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

     [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce]
     "Edit2"="G:\\softwaremy\\RunOnce.exe"
```

with the **double** \\ try importing the registry file..it should work